# Are there default shortcuts for special hyphens and minus sign?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, text-input, unicode

On Mac, *en dash* and *em dash* characters can be typed with `Opt -` and `Opt Shift -`, respectively.

But are there default shortcuts for other bar-like characters, especially for these ones:

- U+00AD SOFT HYPHEN,
- U+2011 NON-BREAKING HYPHEN,
- U+2012 FIGURE DASH,
- U+2212 MINUS SIGN?

I did not find them, but maybe I was not searching properly. If you are going to answer that there are no such shortcuts, please point me to some reliable evidence like an official article on Apple’s website, or a full list of all existing shortcuts in latest version of macOS etc.

Also, my question is about default shortcuts in a freshly-installed system, not for custom settings, tweaking DefaultKeyBinding.dict file, using third-party keyboard managers etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characters you mention are not available on the US layout.  Apple does not publish a list of all the shortcuts, but you can use the Keyboard Viewer to see what each key does.  [This list](https://www.gosquared.com/blog/reference-for-every-character-key-on-a-mac) is old but probably still accurate.

The standard way to access them would be via the Character Viewer (Edit > Emoji & Symbols).  If needed often, then creating a shortcut in System Preferences/Keyboard/Text/Replace  With  would be an option.